# ionic 2 image-picker xcode 8 upgrade - Info.plist permissions error

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework, ionic2, xcode8

Just upgraded to xcode 8 and it appears to break my app on open album, see below for error log. I have uninstalled and installed a number of times, also tried updating my ionic install.

> NOTE: After the xcode 8 upgrade, i had to reinstall ios-sim &
>   ios-deploy (again) as it wasn't being found.

```
ccd[1426]: [access] Refusing TCCAccessRequest for service kTCCServicePhotos and client /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/268F812D-B91E-40A2-943B-7DCF6548CF18/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2FCEDD36-41B6-47A8-B49D-49DC356DA9C3/myAPP_V2.app/myAPP_V2 without NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key

V2[1491]: [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Answer (score 0):

A patch was made available overnight! woo hoo! see below:

[Patch ready for pull](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker/pull/166)